# function static binding in C++

Tags: c++

I am asking about the static binding of the function in C++. What's the data type conversion rules for the function binding.

Suppose we have

```
void func(int x);
void func(long x);
void func(float x);
void func(double x);
void func(char x);
```

and I have one function in main

```
func(1)
```

I know the function func(int x) will be called. I am curious about the rules of that.

Is it always the best match?

Does the order of declaration matter?

In any case the data type conversion will be applied?

What's the concern when the rules are designed?

Comment: Overload resolution rules are a complex topic in C++. For example, try removing the `char` overload, and pass a `char`. The function called is the `int` version. If you then remove the `int` function and still pass `char`, the call will be ambiguous. I think the only way for you to really grasp these rules is reading the Standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it always the best match?

Yes: `1` is an `int`. If an appropriate overload exists, it *will* be taken since this minimizes the number of necessary implicit conversions (none).

> Does the order of declaration matter?

No. However, it matters *whether* a function has been declared before the call is made. If the function is declared *after* the call, it will not be taken into consideration for overload resolution.

> In any case the data type conversion will be applied?

There’s no conversion here because `int` is an exact match. Conversions only come into play when there’s no exact match available.

> What's the concern when the rules are designed?

Well, it’s the only rule that makes sense, isn’t it?

Answer (score 4):

The constant `1` has type `int` so the best match is `void func(int)`. The order of declaration does not affect. Type conversion will come into play when there is a best match (no ambiguity) but the match and the argument don't have the same type as the argument.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ it is always best match. Order of declaration does not matter.
And yes constant has type conversion. For example if You write another overload:

```
void func(std::string const& x);
```

Then call:

```
func("Hi there");
```

Then compiler will use `func(std::string const& x)` overload as `std::string` contain constructor taking `char const *` and use that as one of type conversion rules. Then temporary std::string will be constructed and passed to func.

Answer (score 1):

There are typed constants, for example `1u` for an `unsigned 1` as well as `1l` for a `long 1` and the same with double (`1.0`) and float (`1.0f`).

Comment: Maybe in addition: There is also the constant suffix `1ull` for an `unsigned long long 1`. Looks funny in code.

Comment: so you mean, constant has no type conversion?

Comment: Each constant has a specific type. There may be implicit conversion. So if you do double a = 0.1f; there is an implicit conversion done from float to double. And most times, the compiler will optimize this away (do the conversion in compile time). But this is only done if conversion is needed. In your example, it is not needed and therefore it will also not happen, even not by chance ;).